# How to set an image to UINavigationController's back button

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to set an image to the back button of UINavigationController

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,36,30);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Or use this library. Very easy and good looking result.

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomBackButton

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default back button since it will not let you override it.  Instead you have to use the `leftBarButtonItem` to create a custom "back" button.

More information here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW25

Some prior code to reference: [UINavigation controller button like backButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848381/uinavigation-controller-button-like-backbutton)

Answer (score -2):

Just call `popViewControllerAnimated` on the navigation controller and it will go back.